# Is it possible to know the time spent by a student on a particular topic?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, features

I want to know how much time did a student spent on reading or viewing a topic.

Is it possible to know?

Please tell me

Answer (score 3):

You can use the unload window event.

Will be need make a plugin that send userId, pageId and time information to a controller that store this on database and provide statistics about it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function send_data(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'something.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{data to send},
                success:function(data){
                //get your time in response here
                }
            });
        }
//insert this data in your data base and notice your timestamp


 window.onload=function(){ send_data(); }
 window.onbeforeunload=function(){ send_data(); }

</script>
```

source [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804078/is-it-possible-to-know-how-long-a-user-has-spent-on-a-page)

**edit:**
If the information is provided by a custom component (like online courses) with buttons like **"Prev page"** and **"Next page"** could be implemented a better method to provide this data.

Without loss information

Answer (score 1):

Student on a particular topic? It's not obvious what kind of site you have, its features and extensions used.

However, Joomla core doesn't have any mechanism that can track the time users spend on each pages/articles.

Is it possible? Yes it can be if you develop it.
However have you done any search for extensions that might provide this? I don't believe they will exist, but you never know.